# JAVA - Problem receiving UDP Packets on Linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, udp

Hello i made a simple code to test a program that i was doing.

The code is here:

.
.
.

```
public static final byte precond[] = {(byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF};
public static final byte aftercond[] = {(byte) 0x0a,(byte) 0x00};

String msg = new String(precond) + "challenge rcon" + new String(aftercond);
      String aux = "";

      //Enviar
      DatagramSocket sc2 = new DatagramSocket(27020);
      //sc2.setSoTimeout(5000);
      DatagramPacket pkt = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(),msg.length(),InetAddress.getByName("82.102.15.70"),27050);
      sc2.send(pkt);
      System.out.println("SENT");

      //Receber
      DatagramPacket pkt2 = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024],1024);
      sc2.receive(pkt2);
      String recived = new String(pkt2.getData(),0,pkt2.getLength());
      aux = recived.split(" ")[2].trim();
      sc2.close();
      System.out.println("RECIVED - " + aux);
```

.
.
.

Well this is a simple code the only think it does it's to send a udp packet to a server and server will respond.

The problem it's, this work's on Windows but it DON'T work on ubuntu(server/desktop edition, iam not saying in linux, because i haven't tried in another destro).

I already checked IPtables everything related with router but i can't solve this, the code run until 1st System.out then it block's waiting for the response, but the response on ubuntu never arrived :S

Can some one help please?

Already tried in another server (VPS) and it still the same problem.

Problem is in the 1st packet send!

linux screen: http://img853.imageshack.us/f/linuxr.png

windows screen: http://img339.imageshack.us/f/windowsep.png

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's a difference in what the "default" IP address is.

You're not binding to a specific IP address but are sending to the public IP of the machine.

I'm guessing that in linux you're getting `127.0.0.1` when you call `DatagramSocket sc2 = new DatagramSocket(27020);`

Try:

```
DatagramSocket sc2 = 
    new DatagramSocket(27020, InetAddress.getByName("<my public IP here>"));
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second argument of DatagramScoket been the local IP instead of the destination ip(82.102.15.70)?

Comment: Yes ... I may have read this wrong, I thought he was sending/receiving to the same code. Edited ... that should make more sense regardless.

Comment: ok, i will give it a try. in netstat this is what is shown: udp6       0      0 r1do.csrcon.info:27020  [::]:* - And it still not working if i pass the public IP by argument :S

Comment: see the packets data :| linux screen: http://img853.imageshack.us/f/linuxr.png

windows screen: http://img339.imageshack.us/f/windowsep.png

Comment: if you don't specify a bind-address you get INADDR_ANY, i.e. 0.0.0.0, i.e. all NIC addresses.

Answer (score 1):

it may be due to whether or not the network interface is configured to be promiscuous.  i have some vague recollection that in linux, network interfaces are not usually configured to be promiscuous.  if a network interface is not configured to be promiscuous, it will not receive its own udp packets.

Comment: but i send a packet to IP X and this ip should send me back a reponse to my packet

Answer (score 0):

Check what's *actually* being sent and received on the wire with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org). That should give you more pointers as as to where to look.

Comment: already did it, but i was using tcpdump since my wireshark don't find interfaces in ubuntu.

Comment: Frielspak, make sure to run Wireshark as root (i.e, with `sudo`) if it's not finding interfaces. That's almost always the problem.

Comment: i have the prints now, and i cheked what's being the problem. The difference is in the 1st packet send the bytes in windows are different from unix ones :|

Comment: check the difference in bytes :| linux screen: http://img853.imageshack.us/f/linuxr.png

windows screen: http://img339.imageshack.us/f/windowsep.png

Comment: instead of ff ff ff ff 63 68 61 6c ...(that is the right sequence of bytes), in linux it send bf bd ef ..